# Why is $\text{End}(E)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: ring-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Silverman in his book *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* has given an example of an elliptic curve  $E/K$ with complex multiplication:
$$E: y^2=x^3-x$$

and the map $$[i]:E\longrightarrow E, \ \ \ (x,y)\rightarrow (-x,iy)$$

It is given that,

> There is a ring homomorphism$$\mathbb{Z}[i]\longrightarrow \text{End}(E),\ \ \ m+ni\rightarrow [m]+[n]\circ[i]$$
> If $\text{char}(K)=0$ then  this map is an isomorphism, $\text{End}(E)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i].$

My question is,if $\text{char}(K)=0$ then why does it imply that $\text{End}(E)\cong\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Note:I do not have any knowledge on the theory of Elliptic curves with CM other than the definition.

Comment: How is $[m], [n]$ defined?

Comment: Multiplication by m-map.$[m]:E\longrightarrow E, \ [m]P=P+...+P$,m times if $m>0$ and $[m]P=-P...-P$,-m times if $m<0$,trivial isogeny if m=0.

Comment: Consider their dimension as $\mathbb{Z}$ modules.

Comment: @CyclotomicField $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has dimension 2 but what about End$(E)$?

Comment: It has dimension 2 as well. Can you see why?

Comment: Not sure how,can you explain that?

Comment: @CyclotomicField can you show that $$\dim_{\Bbb Z}(\text{End}(E))=2$$ without resorting to lattices?